# how to load a controller in another controller in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Like php we can import all the functionality of a simple php file name as myfile.php in another file index.php using require "", require_once "", include "" and include_once "". Like this in ruby on rails I want to import a controller file name as products_controller.rb in a another controller file name as home_controller.rb . both files present in the app/controller directory.
In shot i want to import a controller file in another controller file to use all the functions of included controller file

Comment: You probably don't actually want to do that. Perhaps you could explain in more detail what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I generated a scaffold product through this command rails g scaffold products name:string description:text image:string price:decimal 
i used uploader image for image uploading all is working well on localhost:3000/products 
Now i used <%= render template: 'products/index' %> in home/index.html.erb in view directory but i faced error 
NoMethodError in Home#index
 E:/development/backup/final/handicrafts/app/views/products/index.html.erb where line #5 raised: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass Extracted source (around line #5):

Comment: Full error here. 
 2 3 <tbody> 4 5    <% @products.each do |product| %> 6         <tr> 7 8             <td> <%= product.name%></td>          Trace of template inclusion: app/views/home/index.html.erb  Rails.root: E:/development/backup/final/handicrafts  Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace app/views/products/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_products_index_html_erb___39254587_70804752' app/views/home/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_home_index_html_erb___716772540_68965992'

Comment: But when i copy all method from products_controller.rb in home_controller.rb i solved the problem it self and it was working well in home/index.html.erb So i want to import all method from products_controller.rb in home_controller.rb. So please tell me all the ways to do instead to copy the code. like inherit that class, inherit that methods and also tell me about module for the same. and also tell me can i use require "" to access the products_controller.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the above problem you generate scaffold product and you want to render index action of product controller in home controller but you are getting undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass Extracted source Error.

Try this

in view/homes/index.html.erb

```
<%= render :template=>"products/index" %>
```

now come to the controllers/homes_controller.rb

in

```
def index
    @products=product.all
end
```